# Find PDA Publick key with bump, seeds and programId

Tags: pda

I know everything about a PDA, except his public key, is there a way with JS to get the public key of the PDA knowing bump, seeds and programId ?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the PDA account using it seeds and programID, and then check if the obtained bump is the same as the one you have.

You have to use [**`findProgramAddress`**](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/PublicKey.html#findProgramAddress) method on solana web3 (or anchor too), this will return the PublicKey of the PDA + the bump.

Comment: I agree but if the bump returned is not the same then I have now way to find the public key.

Comment: That will be a really weird case, because anchor and Solana will always return the FIRST BUMP, so if your bump is different, then that means that you are using the seed wrongly

Answer (score 2):

```
const [pda, bump] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
    [
        publicKey.toBuffer(),  <--- public key as seed
        Buffer.from('SEED')    <--- hardcoded string as seed
    ],
    programId
)
```

or you can use createProgramAddress and specify the bump seed

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/cd343f7/src/publickey.ts#L191

here's a good article about PDAs and bumps:
https://www.sec3.dev/blog/pda-bump-seeds